# What algorithms exist for Polynomial Interpolation of arbitrary degree in two variables.

Tags: polynomials, finite-fields, interpolation, interpolation-theory

Is there a way to take a set of points $((x_0, x_1), y)$ of arbitrary length and interpolated them into a polynomial of pre-defined degree.

So we would have a function $y = f(x_0, x_1) = (a_0) + (a_1 x_0 + a_2 x_1) + (a_3 x_0 x_1 + a_4 x_0^2 + a_5 x_1^2) + degree 3 + degree 4 + ...$.

I'm interested in the case where we can pre-define the degree of the polynomial say 100. Furthermore, I'm interested in the case of Integers and even integers in some Finite Field (specifically of characteristic 2 e.g. $2^8$).

## Edit

The polynomial function takes two variables as input and the output is a third variable.

I'm looking a form of [Multivariant Interpolation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_interpolation) that takes two variables but the degree of the polynomial is large e.g. degree 100.

Comment: one can try exact [Lagrange Interpolation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_polynomial) or best-fit [Polynomial Regression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_regression)

Comment: @NikosM. I think Lagrange Interpolation only works on polynomials in one variables correct? Is there a way to generalise it to two variables?
Looks like polynomial regression (at least in the wikipedia article) is also in one variable.

Comment: I dont know if there is Lagrange interpolation for more than one variable, but polynomial regression can be used with any number of variables, polynomial regression is simply multi-dimensional linear regression on $x_1$,$x_2$,$x_1^2$,$x_2^2$,$x_1x_2$ if considered as separate variables

Comment: Excellent thanks! I'll give that ago.

Comment: @NikosM. You do realize that the asker lives in the real of finite fields, where there is no concept of distance, and hence the idea of a best match is absurd, because an exact match is required, I think.

Comment: The space of bivariate polynomials of degree $n$ has dimension $\binom{n+2}2$. When that exceeds the number of points, you would expect the system to have a solution. But, unlike in the single variable case, when we get an invertible Vandermoonde matrix, the existence of a solution may not be guaranteed.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen, my suggestion was for interpolation/fitting over the reals. I am not aware of interpolation over finite fields

Comment: @NikosM. I thought so. Can you get an exact match with those methods. Without a concept of distance between two numbers things like *mean square error* go out of the window, I think :-)

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen, well the algorithm still works even over finite fields, but MSE minimisation property no longer holds. So it provides a solution but now this solution has different properties, if these properties satisfy the OP is another issue. But I dont know of an analog of least-squares algorithm for finite fields

Comment: For example, if all the points lie on the line $x_1=x_0$, then the second variable doesn't really add anything, and the condition a few comments up is not sufficient.